# AngularJS + Bootstrap, datepicker is invalid with prepopulated data

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have this form, 
and on this form,
I have a control,
this control is a datepicker. It looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : !orderLine.required.$pristine && orderLine.required.$invalid || !orderLine.required }">
    <label class="control-label">Required date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="required" ng-model="controller.orderLine.dates.required" datepicker-popup show-weeks="false" is-open="controller.calendar.open" required />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="controller.openCalendar($event)"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    valid: {{ !orderLine.required.$invalid }}
</div>
```

As you can see, this is a required field.
If I pull in some data from the server and populate this field with the value, the control is still marked as invalid.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you checked date format in server and in your datepicker.

Comment: Where is demo that replicates this?